# Simple dataset query

Tags: dataset, query

Why does taking a `Part` fail in a `Dataset` query function when there is an operation in the index argument?

```
dataset = Dataset[Table[<|"a" -> n|>, {n, 3}]];

dataset[All, Range[4][[#a]]&]
```

[image]

```
dataset[All, Range[4][[#a + 1]]&]
```

[image]

To get it to work I need to use `Extract` instead:

```
dataset[All, Extract[Range[4], {#a + 1}]&]
```

[image]

Are there other workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is concerned with `Association`'s `HoldAllComplete` attribute.

```
Attributes[Association]
```

> ```
> {HoldAllComplete, Protected}
> ```

I am not completely certain of the internal workings but it appears that the `a# + 1` expression is being held unevaluated when passed to `Part`. Wrapping the expression in `Evaluate` to force evaluation does not appear to help.

```
dataset[All, Range[4][[Evaluate[#a + 1]]] &]
```

> Message: Plus[1, Atom[Integer]] is not a valid part specification.

However, you there is a workaround by passing the expression as a parameter to a pure function.

```
dataset[All, Range[4][[#]] &@(#a + 1) &]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
 ds = Dataset[Table[<|"a" -> n|>, {n, 3}]];
 ds[All, "a", # + 1 &]
```

[image: ds]

BTW, you 1st query can be simplified to

```
ds[All, "a"]
```